# Should I fix my swimming pool with plaster or a clorinated rubber?

Tags: repair, plaster, pool

I have below ground swimming pool. The plaster is cracking and pealing off. I need to apply new plaster or another type of coating. I am wondering whether it would be easier to apply a coating of clorinated rubber?

Does anyone have experience with this type of coating that they could share?

Comment: How old is the pool?  How big are the affected areas?

Comment: From what I understand old pools have longer lasting plaster (because of the hazardous materials that were used that are now outlawed) so it's best to keep it around for as long as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Bring in a professional and verify what is actually going on, this is not a DIY job.
Also, rather than replastering consider going to an aggregate pool finish like Pebble Tec - much more durable and easier to care for.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that its the plaster (marbilite?) that is flaking off... it may actually be that you have paint or fibreglass that is actually flaking (if you have that)...

Generally, repairs to the marbilite require you draining and re-plastering the pool...

One of your options is to apply a fibreglass coating over the old surface of the pool, this would renew the lusture of the pool and would make the surface nice and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand from your question the flaking seems to be more probable a painted substance over you exsisting pool finish . if thats the case you would need to sand blast off all areas of pool and then replaster or refinish with what ever material you choose