# Pool plaster strengthening additive which reduces cracks

Tags: concrete, plaster, pool

Does anyone know of an additive to add into pool plaster when it's being mixed to help reduce the chance of fine cracks later on?  Perhaps some sort of bonding agent or polymer?  I couldn't seem to find anything online so maybe this doesn't exist?

Comment: [Related question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/should-i-fix-my-swimming-pool-with-plaster-or-a-clorinated-rubber) with answers.

Comment: Reviewed the other question but it's not the same thing I'm asking unfortunately